# How to combine this String with LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a LINQ query. It has to combine the matching string with **" "** as a single string value. I tried the below code with my model. But showing:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Aggregate[String](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.String],
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Please suggest me how can i write a query to combine the set of strings into a single string.

**Code**

```
BTags = Db.BibContents.Where(x => x.BibId == q.BibId && x.TagNo == "245")
        .Select(x => x.NormValue)
        .Aggregate((s, x) => s + " " + x).FirstOrDefault()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Why not use [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) like:

```
string str = string.Join(" ", Db.BibContents
                               .Where(x => x.BibId == q.BibId && x.TagNo == "245")
                               .Select(x => x.NormValue));
```

Comment: I was using inside my model.